# FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been making a realtime textbox using firebox. The workflow is something like this, a url with the textbox is given, and if someone opens up the same url in realtime, he/she should see the exact textbox content. I am getting a warning :

```
<html>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);


    var database = firebase.database().ref(); //get a reference to firebase database service
var textboxRef = database.child('textbox'); //Get a reference to the "textbox" child
var $textbox = $('#textbox'); //Saves a reference to the textarea element using jQuery

//When anything changes (added, removed, updated) in the "textbox" child in the database
textboxRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log("From Firebase:", snapshot.val());
  $textbox.val(snapshot.val().text); //Set the value of the textarea to the value returned by Firebase (specifically the "text" property of the "textbox" child)
});

//When any key is released while the textarea is in focus
$textbox.keyup(function() {
  //Updates the properties and values in the database child called "textbox" with the object provided. The "set" function is used instead of the "update" function so that if the database child "textbox" of its properties are removed, this will create it as well as update it
  textboxRef.set({
    text: $textbox.val()
  });
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<textarea name="textbox" id="textbox" placeholder="Type here"></textarea>

</html>
```

I am very new to Firebase Realtime Database, too.